# Discord.py: How to get the colors of the roles?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my first bot for discord. What I'm trying to achieve is to get the color of all the roles in a server. How can I do that? I searched but I found only how to set a color of a role and not how to get the current color. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
@client.command()
async def roles_colors(ctx):
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        await ctx.send(role.name)
        await ctx.send(discord.role.color)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the colour of a `discord.Role` object with `.colour`.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Role.colour

You can get all the Roles of a `discord.Guild` object with `.roles`. (A discord guild is a discord server.)
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Guild.roles

If your question is how to get the rendered colour of a Discord Member (member with multiple coloured roles) you just access `.colour` on the `discord.Member` object.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=roles#discord.Member.colour

**edit**:

```
@client.command()
async def roles_colors(ctx):
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        await ctx.send(role.name)
        await ctx.send(role.color)
```

You wrote `discord.role.color`, should be `role.color`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, but I get an error, I modified the code. Can you please check if I'm doing something wrong? (I edited the question adding the code)

Comment: Thank you a lot, you solved my error. Have a nice day.